# write string to textblock on different page in C#, UWP

Tags: c#, asynchronous, uwp, textblock

How can I write into a `TextBlock` on a different page?
So far it only works with `TextBlocks` on the same page.
The `async` function is in `Page_1`. The `TextBlock` is on `Page_2`.

```
public async void Serial() 
{
   string rxBuffer;
   //code
   //code
   //code

   while (true)
   {
      textblock_DebugRx_Gas_live.Text = rxBuffer;    
   } 
}
```

Comment: I guess we need more details, but maybe you can try using ApplicationData: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data

Comment: simply you need to create a Common Class as - `CommonClass` and declare a static string object as - `txtObj` then on `Page_1` pass value to common class as- `CommonClass.txtObj = "your string"` and then on `Page_2` load pass the value to `TextBlock` as - `txtBlock.text = CommonClass.txtObj` also you can pass data from `Frame.Navigate`

Comment: @TonicLoyal: Do you have a reference to `Page_2` in `Page_1` or where is the the `Page_2` that you are trying to access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> write string to textblock on different page in C#, UWP

If the two page display in foreground at same time like following.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Margin="0,20,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Click" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="Tbk" />
    </StackPanel>

    <Frame Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <local:TestPage />
    </Frame>
</Grid>
```

You could use [`Messenger`](http://mvvmlight.net/) to send message from original page to target page.

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging;

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var message = "Test";
    Messenger.Default.Send<string,TestPage>(message);
    Tbk.Text = message;
}
```

**Target Page**

```
public TestPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += TestPage_Loaded;
}

private void TestPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Messenger.Default.Register<string>(this, (s) =>
    {
        MyTextBlock.Text = s;
    });
}
```

Comment: This is awesome. It works perfectly. Ones the NuGet is installed, it's just so easy :)

Answer (score 2):

Usually, pages are displayed one at a time, so if you want to pass data between them during navigation, you should do so using the second parameter of the `Frame.Navigate` method:

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage), someString);
```

However, an even better solution is to use some kind of MVVM framework, which has a navigation service based on ViewModels, which have a longer lifetime than the UI controls/page. Frameworks like MvvvmCross, MvvmLight, SimpleMvvm or Reactive UI can all help you write such logic in an easier manner.

In your case, you could store the updated state in a view model, which would then be shared by both pages, so any change would be reflected in both places. Instead of directly writing into the `Text` property of the `TextBlocks`, you would implement a view model with a `string` property, which would trigger `PropertyChanged` event from the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. The MVVM pattern is well described in many tutorials so I encourage you to dig into it.