# How to bind a visibility of HamburgerButtonInfo to another viewmodel other than ShellViewModel?

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, uwp-xaml

**Question**

1. How can I change the visibility of my hamburger button by not using shellviewmodel ?
   P.s. : Its an UWP app working on template10.
2. Is it possible to bind the Hamburger button visibility to two different Viewmodels in template10?

**Shell.xaml**

```
xmlns:vm="using:ScanWorx.ViewModels"
xmlns:converters="using:ScanWorx.ViewModels"

<Page.DataContext>
    <vm:ShellViewModel x:Name="ViewModel" />
</Page.DataContext>

<Page.Resources>
    <converters:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="Converter" />
</Page.Resources>

<controls:HamburgerMenu x:Name="MyHamburgerMenu">
    <controls:HamburgerMenu.PrimaryButtons>
        <!--  HeatMap Generator Button  -->
        <controls:HamburgerButtonInfo  ClearHistory="True" PageType="views:HeatMapGeneratorPage" 
                                       Visibility="{x:Bind vm:LoginPageViewModel.abc, Mode=TwoWay, 
                                                    Converter={StaticResource Converter}}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <SymbolIcon
                    Width="48"
                    Height="48"
                    Symbol="ViewAll" />
                <TextBlock
                    Margin="12,0,0,0"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Text="HeatMap Generator" />
            </StackPanel>
        </controls:HamburgerButtonInfo>

    </controls:HamburgerMenu.PrimaryButtons>
</controls:HamburgerMenu>
```

**LoginPageViewModel.cs**

```
namespace ScanWorx.ViewModels
{
   class LoginPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
   {
      public static bool abc { get; set; }
      public static Visibility visibility1 { get; set; }

      public async void Button_Login_Click()
      {
         try
         {
            *code to decrypt my login details and then after decryptng i check for next condition*
            if (ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["UserAccessLevel"].ToString() == "Administrator")
            {
                abc = true;
                visibility1 = Visibility.Visible;
            }
            else
            {
                abc = false;
                visibility1 = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**ShellViewModel.cs** :

- If i use shellviewModel in binding The hiding works fine by changing - `Visibility="{x:Bind vm:ShellViewModel.ShowButton}` , but with this it can only be hard coded either false or true making it visible or collapsed once when app starts.
- But i dont want to change the visibility of my button with shell view model i want to change it after i log in with the LoginPageViewModel*

  ```
   namespace ScanWorx.ViewModels
   {
      class ShellViewModel : ViewModelBase
      {
         public static bool ShowButton { get; set; }

         public ShellViewModel()
         {
           ShowButton = false;
         }
      }
   }
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to bind a visibility of HamburgerButtonInfo to another viewmodel other than ShellViewModel?

The better way is make a global setting class to record if login. After login success, edit the setting class ShowButton bool property to true.

**Setting.cs**

```
public class Setting : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _showBtn = false;
    public bool ShowBtn
    {
        get { return _showBtn; }
        set { _showBtn = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**Xaml bind**

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:Setting x:Key="Setting"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>

......

Visibility="{Binding ShowBtn, Source={StaticResource Setting}}"
```

**Value Change**

```
((Setting)Application.Current.Resources["Setting"]).ShowBtn = true;
```

Comment: Hi @Nico , Thank you for your reply.  I tried this approach But I have to work on  `<Page.Resources>` so application.resources dont work . i tried adding the setting.cs in Page.Resources `<Page.Resources>
        <converters:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="Converter" />
        <local1:setting x:Key="Setting"/>
    </Page.Resources>` but it only works when i set the _showBtn = false or true once. When i make a value change in other ViewModel.cs it doesnt update the shell.

Comment: it need to set as global that is why I place the setting class in Application Resource.  And you have another way to approach that make a messagecenter to broadcast the value change for more please refer this case [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58178093/7254781).

Comment: I put this value change `((Setting)Application.Current.Resources["Setting"]).ShowBtn = true;` in the condition of my `LoginPageViewModel.cs` snippet above. But the change in value doesnt reflect on the visibility of the button. the visibiilty is only set once in setting.cs at `private bool _showBtn = false;`

Comment: I have upload the code sample, and it [works](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/TestBind) well, (Click the Submit button for testing)

Comment: Hey , Thanks alot . It works fine now :) only problem now is I just need to reset the visibility of the button now because it is set to true even if i log out. when i login as a new user who is not "Administrator" it still shows me the button. which is i guess because the value of public `bool ShowBtn` is set to true because of my previous login. any help regarding this would be appreciated like how i can reset the visibility back to false after i log out.  Thanks again, have a nice day !

Comment: The same to you, have a nice day.